# How can I adapt a custom Powershell host to a WPF user interface while supporting I/O from programs run in the host?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm trying to adapt the Host03 sample found here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706577(v=vs.85).aspx) to use a WPF interface. I've attempted to complete this by creating a custom StringWriter and StringReader and setting the Console.Out and Console.In to my custom classes. Here is what the prototype code looks like:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ConsoleWriter _consoleWriter;
    private TextWriter _textWriter;
    private ConsoleReader _consoleReader;
    private TextReader _textReader;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _textWriter = Console.Out;
        _textReader = Console.In;
        _consoleWriter = new ConsoleWriter(ref tb);
        Console.SetOut(_consoleWriter);
        tb.KeyUp += OnTextInputKeyUp;
    }

    private void OnTextInputKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            _consoleReader = new ConsoleReader(tb.Text);
            Console.SetIn(_consoleReader);
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
// I'm creating a thread here, because otherwise the following exception occurs:
// "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"
            var t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
                delegate
                    {
// PSListenerConsoleSample is the class used in the Host03 sample which I am trying to adapt
// The execute method in PShellListener has been made public for prototype purposes,
// in the sample it is private
                        var listener = new PSListenerConsoleSample();
                        listener.Execute(input);
                    }));
            t.Start();
        }
    }

    ~MainWindow()
    {
        Console.SetOut(_textWriter);    // Redirect Console back to original TextWriter. 
        Console.SetIn(_textReader);
        _consoleWriter.Close();         // Close our ConsoleWriter TextWriter. 
    }
}

public class ConsoleWriter : StringWriter
{
    private TextBox _textBox;

    public ConsoleWriter(ref TextBox textBox)
    {
        _textBox = textBox;
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        if (_textBox.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            _textBox.Text += value + "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            _textBox.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                       (Action)(() => { _textBox.Text += "\n" + value + "\n"; }));
        }
    }
}
public class ConsoleReader : StringReader
{
    private string _s;

    public ConsoleReader(string s) : base(s)
    {
        _s = s;
    } 

    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        return _s;
    }
}
}
```

The ConsoleReader class currently returns all the displayed text, so it is only designed to work for the first command entered. For example, if I enter "ls" and press enter, the contents of my bin\debug directory are displayed. The problem is that I am trying to support programs that require I/O. For example, consider the following console application:

```
namespace DemoQuestion
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, I am the program you just called. Please enter something:");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("I received the following input from you: {0}", input);
        }
    }
}
```

This simple program executes fine in the Host03 sample, prompting the user for input and then reading and displaying it. In my adapted example, if I enter "T:\DemoQuestion.exe" the initial Console.WriteLine occurs, displaying "Hello, I am, etc...", but I'm unable to figure out how to get user input back into program.

I apologize for the complexity of the question, I tried my best to simplify it. Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion. It may be nontrivial to write a console-like GUI from scratch that can handle both input and output, maybe that's why PowerShell ISE did not have one until PowerShell 3.0. So, maybe you should try to do what was done in PowerShell ISE before 3.0. Have two separate UI element, one for input, one for output.